# Merging a C struct factory function with its corresponding C++ wrapping class constructor

Tags: c++, wrapper

Consider writing a C++ wrapper for a C library with the following (`T` is some other type):

```
typedef struct { /*fields*/ } S;

S* alloc_S(const T*);
void free_S(S*);
```

I want to write a class `class_S` inheriting from `S` so that calls to `alloc_S` and `free_S` are hidden away thanks to, respectively, `class_S::class_S(const T*)` and `class_S::~class_S()` (removing the risk of forgetting a call to `free_S`).

As `alloc_S` already allocates and assigns values to all the fields of the structure it returns, is there an elegant way to build the rest of the `class_S` object "around" that structure?

My goal is to avoid the overhead (in time and space) of something like

```
class_S::class_S(const T* t)
{
    S* tmp = alloc_S(t);
    // deep-copy tmp into this
    free_S(tmp);
}
```

Obviously, instead of inheriting from `S`, I could write `class_S` to have a `S*` member and work with it but, if possible, I would like to avoid this approach.

Comment: Two questions: (1) Do you have any control over the C library's implementation? (2) Why are you so eager to inherit from `S`?

Comment: (1) Nope (2) To allow a similar syntax when accessing the fields of `class_S` as compared to accessing the ones of `S` and to allow `static_cast<S*>`ing `class_S*` to easily pass them back to the C API. Of course, the "`S*` member" approach allows both but not as neatly ...

Comment: I think you are trying to do too much for too little with `class_S`. The way I see it, all you need is a `std::unique_ptr<S> make_S(T const*)` function.

Comment: Unrelated: `typedef struct { /*fields*/ } S;` is bogus. Embrace C++ and use `struct S{ /*fields*/ };`

Comment: @PiCTo: "*the "`S*` member" approach allows both but not as neatly*" - perhaps, but it is the *correct* solution if you need a wrapper class. Make sure to disable the copy constructor (unless the API provides a function for making copies of `S`). Otherwise, just forget `class_S` altogether, just use `std::unique_ptr<S>` instead, likeStoryTeller suggested. You can use `free_S()` as a custom deleter for it, eg: `std::unique_ptr<S, decltype(&free_S)> s(alloc_S(t), &free_S);`

Comment: @user4581301 "a C library with the following"

Answer (score 0):

Here's one non-standard, confusing and unmaintainable way - note the special construction syntax

```
#include <memory>


extern "C" {

    struct T {};

    struct S
    {
    };

    S* alloc_S(T*);
    void free_S(S*);
}


struct class_S : S
{
    void * operator new (std::size_t,  T* p)
    {
        return alloc_S(p);
    }

    void operator delete(void *p)
    {
        if (p) free_S(reinterpret_cast<S*>(p));
    }
};

int main()
{
    T t;
    auto ps = new (&t) class_S;


    delete ps;
}
```

On balance you're probably better off using a unique_ptr with custom deleter:

```
struct class_S
{
    struct deleter {
        void operator()(S*p) const noexcept {
            free_S(p);
        }
    };

    class_S(T* p) : impl_(alloc_S(p), deleter()) {}

    // add proxy methods as required

    std::unique_ptr<S, deleter> impl_;
};

int main()
{
    T t;
    auto mys = class_S(&t);
}
```